# Equivalance of `required=True` and `IS_NOT_IN_DB` in web2py's pyDAL

Tags: web2py, pydal

The web2py book gives [an example of modelling an image blog](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#An-image-blog). The lines of code relevant to my question are:

```
db.define_table('image',
                Field('title', unique=True),
                Field('file', 'upload'),
                format = '%(title)s')

db.image.title.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, db.image.title)
```

The text states that expressions like `db.image.title.requires` are validators. But

1. It does not make it clear whether `unique=True` in the expresssion `Field('title', unique=True)` is also a validator with the exact same functionality
2. What impact a validator has on database-driven form generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the book:

> Notice that `requires=...` is enforced at the level of forms, `required=True` is enforced at the level of the DAL (insert), while `notnull`, `unique` and `ondelete` are enforced at the level of the database. While they sometimes may seem redundant, it is important to maintain the distinction when programming with the DAL.

`unique=True` does *not* result in a validator being created. It results in a `UNIQUE` constraint being added to the database schema when web2py first creates the table in the database (assuming you have enabled migrations). If you call the DAL `.insert()` or `.update()` methods with values that would violate this constraint, the database will throw an error (which will result in a Python exception in your app).

Setting `requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(...)` creates a validator, which will be run when you (a) submit a form created using `SQLFORM` or (b) call the DAL `.validate_and_insert()` or `.validate_and_update()` methods. If validation fails, the insert/update is not sent to the database at all, and you do not get a Python exception, but simply a record of the failure (which is typically displayed on the form in the case of a form submission).

If you will be making inserts and updates via forms, it is a good idea to use the validator, because it provides the proper user experience (i.e., displaying an error message with the form). It is also a good idea to set `unique=True` so the database has the appropriate schema, in case you make inserts/updates via means other than forms (and possibly even outside of web2py or the DAL).